# Generalizing objects with Parent Class Vs Generalizing classes implementing a common interface

Tags: flash, actionscript

I apologize if my comparison seems wierd, but still trying to clear my confusions...

Take this example 
DisplayObjectContainer.addChild (DisplayObject) -

one can pass in a Sprite, a Shape, a MovieClip, etc. -- they all inherit DisplayObject, so they all can be added to the display list.

---

I wanna know, isn't this behaviour similar to the classes that implement the same interface. I could never implement it in my projects, but studied that classes that implement same interfaces, can be used variably in place of each other. What can be the practical example for this ( similar to one i used above for classes and subclasses) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you example could have been a good one as well.
All your objects could have implemented IDisplayable with it's method Display.

And DisplayContainer could have been a collection of IDisplayable.

A duck is a bird, a duck can fly
An Ostrich is a bird, an Ostrich can't fly
A plane isn't a bird, but can fly.

So if you implement Fly on Bird, you have to say a plane is a bird....
If you implement Fly on FlyingThingy, you have to say an ostrich is a flying thing...

If you create an Interface IFlier, and then implement it for duck and plane, now your description is accurate. I've chosen fairly obvious classes here, but when you get deep into someone else's code, or even your own after a few months of doing something else, reading a plane is a bird, or Ostrich.Fly, knocks you right off your perch.